# Http error code 403 after deploying to Firebase Hosting

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I created a simple Spring Boot application which I host on Heroku.
I access this backend application with a Flutter Web client.

When I run the Flutter Web client locally on my machine everything works like a charm until I deploy it via Firebase Hosting.

Then suddenly the requests to the Spring Boot application at Heroku fail with

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/endpoint" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=4c594a7e-4e0b-8d69-0987867cc203 fwd="87.135.1.137" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=53ms status=403 bytes=221 protocol=https
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: An [OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is commonly part of making requests from different domains. Is the flutter app and backed API on different domains/subdomains?

Comment: @abraham yes they are.

Comment: You'll have to configure the APi to allow the client domain to make requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by annotating my Controller class with `@CrossOrigin`.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
class ResponseController(val service: Service) {

    @GetMapping("/endpoint")
    @ResponseBody
    suspend fun response(): ResponseWrapper = service.getResponse()
}
```